# Reference request for studying on space forms

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I would like to study on [Space form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_form), But I dont know what book or notes are suitable for beginning basically.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

J.Wolf "Spaces of Constant Curvature" would be a place to start. You can also try to read Thurston's "Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology" in order to see how much hyperbolic case differs from the other two.